# c function to invert a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to make a function that gets a line of text and then inverts every word and returns an array of strings. This is my code. Something is obviously wrong. Any suggestions on my mistakes here ?

```
char** function(char* str, int* pn)
{
    char temp[21];
    int n_of_spaces = 0, i = 0, d = 0;

    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            n_of_spaces++;

    *pn = n_of_spaces + 1;      //should be number of words
    char** s = (char**)calloc(*pn, sizeof(char*));

    while (str[i]) 
    {
        d = 0;
        if (i != 0)
            i++;

        while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != 0)
        {
            i++;
            d++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
            temp[j] = str[i];

        for (int k = 0; k < *pn; k++) 
        {
            s[k] = (char*)calloc(d + 1, sizeof(char));
            strcpy(s[k], temp);
            invert(s[k]);       //inverts a word
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

//heres main

```
int main()
{
    int n_of_words;
    char line[100];
    gets(line);
    char** s = function(line, &n_of_words);

    for (int i = 0; i < n_of_words; i++) 
    {
        puts(s[i]);
        free(s[i]);
    }

    free(s);
    return 0;
}
void invert(char* s)
{
int t;
for (int i = 0, j = strlen(s) - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
{
    t = s[i];
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = t;
}
```

}

Comment: run-time error, it does nothing, apparently

Comment: Can you step through this with a debugger?

Comment: that' s just one function of the code, but I think logic behind it is wrong

Comment: and, yes, it compiles, but not doing anything literally

Comment: Take a look at [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split a string.

Comment: i'll post main function in a moment

Comment: on allocation of memory, professor told me there's basiclly no big difference

Comment: _Something is_ ***obviously*** _wrong_.  Not from your description.  If you have not already run it through a debugger, do so.  If you have, then post your specific observations from that run.

Comment: "Exception thrown at 0x777A6EDD (ntdll.dll) in _PROJECT_.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x202020CC."

Comment: Where is `invert(...)` defined. Put it in your code.

Comment: 1. This is **not** a minimal, **complete**, example that **we** can use to reproduce your problem. 2. You never terminate `temp[]` before performing the eventual `strcpy(s[k], temp)` (and that assumes everything else went *right* up until that point, which is highly questionable).

Comment: Also I see that you fill temp array only with one value. In your for cycle where `temp[j] = str[i]` i remains the same

Comment: Need reset `i` before `while (str[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all do not use `gets`, it can cause buffer overflow because you do not exactly know the number of bytes which will be read. Use `fgets` instead.

Secondly, do not cast result of `malloc` and `calloc` to your pointer type. It can cause you missing some important warnings.

On top of that like Yuriy Ivaskevych said you should better use `strtok` function in order to split your string.

After all of that your `temp` variable has static size of 21 which can be overflowed when you copy data into it. And when you actually copy the data, you do not set the string termination character `\0`. Therefore when you call `strcpy` it can not find the end of the string and you get undefined behavior

Comment: You should probably list all the problems as this is just one of many that is causing this code not to work as expected.

Comment: @ChrisTurner it is hard to notice all. Look at the update, please, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: It was more that you mentioned one of the more obvious problems in the comments that I was thinking of.

Comment: The other glaring issue is the repeated re-allocation of the entire contents of `s[]` - only need to allocate space for the current word `k`

Answer (score 0):

This does not reverse each word, but it illustrates how to reverse the input line. ( i.e. provides an example addressing the title question, a *c function to invert a string*) It is intended to show a simplified approach, and hopefully one that you can use to expand into what you want to do.

Note the following:

1) the prototype of the `main` function changed.
2) the prototype of `function()` changed.
3) use of `strdup()` instead of calloc(). (to simplify)
4) all of the work is done in `function()`, i.e. no `invert()`.

This will compile and run to reverse an input string up to 99 characters.

```
char* function(char* str, int* pn)
{
    if(!str) return "";
    char *newStr = strdup(str);
    int len, i=0;
    len = strlen(str);
    while(str[i])
    {
        newStr[len-1-i]=str[i];
        i++;
    }
    str[i]=0;
    strcpy(str, newStr);
    free(newStr);

    *pn = i-1;

    return str;
}

//heres main

int main(void)
{
    int n_of_words;
    char line[100];
    char line2[100];
    gets(line);

    strcpy(line2, function(line, &n_of_words));

    printf( "reversed line: %s", line2);

    return 0;
}
```

*EDIT* (to address comment)
***Suggested approach for breaking string into*** *words****:***
1) Use a two step read, first read to *count* spaces, and *longest* word.
2) Use information in step one to create space for *count* strings, each *longest*+1 long. Suggest using separate functions to create/free this memory, eg:

```
char ** Create2DStr(int numStrings, int maxStrLen)
{
    int i;
    char **a = {0};
    a = calloc(numStrings, sizeof(a));
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
      a[i] = calloc(maxStrLen + 1, 1);
    }
    return a;
}

void free2DStr(char ** a, int numStrings)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]) free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
}
```

3) The second read through the original string is to break it into "words" and place each "word" into the strings you created.  Do this in a loop *count* +1 times.  There are many approaches that will work, `strtok(...)` to parse on spaces, or a byte-by-byte character assignment into each string, indexing the loop each  time `byte==space`.
4) In a subsequent loop, process each of your new strings through the `function()` above to reverse the character order.

Comment: not sure how this is meant to be useful as it doesn't address the issues in the question

Comment: @ChrisTurner -  Title is _c function to invert a string_.  This illustrates a much simplified approach, and is offered as an alternative to some of the very problems you mention in other comments.